# Bing Maps Distance Matrix API has a different result than Bing Maps (browser)

Tags: excel-formula, bing-maps

I am very new to the Bing Maps API, am reading around a lot, but I also felt lost.

```
GEO LOC A: 1.543875, 110.410586
GEO LOC B: 1.547163, 110.415068
```

I formulated this URL:

**URL**: https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=1.543875,110.410586&destinations=1.547163,110.415068&o=xml&travelMode=driving&key=bingmapskey

Then I use `XML = WEBSERVICE(URL)`

Then my distance `= FILTERXML(XML,"//TravelDistance[1]") = 0.154km`

If you use Bing Maps, it is 1.3 km:

https://www.bing.com/maps/

[Snapshot of the Bing Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ3AB.png)

The difference is about 1 km.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you entered the different information in Bing Maps. I just tried the coordinates you provided and got a completely different map. Here is a direct link to the query:

[https://www.bing.com/maps?osid=6a9420ba-ba4a-47cf-9ac8-ca6bc34963aa&cp=1.546032~110.416322&lvl=17&v=2&sV=2&form=S00027](https://www.bing.com/maps?osid=6a9420ba-ba4a-47cf-9ac8-ca6bc34963aa&cp=1.546032%7E110.416322&lvl=17&v=2&sV=2&form=S00027)

[image]